# Grub Rescue error unable to boot into ubuntu after updateing windows on triple booted Laptop

Tags: grub2, windows, rescue-mode

I had a Acer laptop in which I triple booted Windows 10, Kali Linux, and Ubuntu. Yesterday, I updated my windows to fall creators update and when Windows restarted it showed error: no such partition. Entering rescue mode... grub rescue> and then I tried Online tutorials and used set prefix method and I booted into Kali linux partition and I opened up kali linux's boot loader from where I am able to boot into either Windows 10 or kali linux but there is no option fir Ubuntu which is my primary OS and when I boot into windows and go to partition manager it is showing my ubuntu partition as free space. PLEASE HELP me to get my ubuntu partition back it had all my important files and softwares.

Comment: I can't comment, so I need to ask it here, what does your current partition table look like, use gparted or parted, or even Disk Management on windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Comment: My Gparted on kali linux and Disk management on windows show partition of windows 10 and kali linux as they were but the ubuntu partition is shown as free space or unallocated

Comment: Ok i will try it..!!

Comment: Windows 10 probably made a new diag partition and deleted the ubuntu partition to make room, but I need to see te actual partition table to see if that is the issue.

Comment: Can I get back my data.?

Comment: If the issue is what I think it is, probably. In all cases I've seen windows shrunk one of its own partitions and only removed the partition from the partition table

Comment: In the above situation is it possible to recover important data?

Comment: In that situation yes

Comment: How can I do so.? Please help.!

Comment: Boot Kali, in a terminal run `sudo fdisk -l`, copy the output here

Comment: Yes, It is listing all the partitions

Comment: And it showing partition 4 which is of extended type, does not start on physical sector boundary

Comment: can you copy the output here

Comment: Here is the link to the screen shot-->> https://send.firefox.com/download/5083b77356/#Y-Ti6XBR_Zebxx6b5KnDvQ

Comment: It does look like windows made a new primary partition by shrinking the main windows partition. (if you add the 2nd and 3rd partition sizes you end up with a nice round 390gb partition. So that new partition did not overwrite your Ubuntu partition. Now you need to use cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk to recover your files

Comment: I figured out that my Ubuntu partition which was in /dev/sda4 is deleted and now it is being shown as free space

Comment: And I tried testdisk but it stopped after some time and its taking too long. The estimated time was over 40 hours to recover

Comment: And actually the /dev/sda4 partition is missing. All other partition like sda1, sda2, sda3, sda5, sda6, etc are present